# How to test license validation via REST API

Tags: php, rest, phpunit, testcase

Please consider the following PHP code

```
static public function IsLicenseValid($domain)
{
    if (empty($domain)) {
        throw new Exception;
    }

    $licenseResponse = Curl::Post(['hostname' => $domain]);

        $Xml     = new XML();
        $xmlTree = $Xml->XMLToTree($licenseResponse);

        if ($xmlTree['is_valid'] == 'true') {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I am writing test case using PHPUnit to check the above method. I am able to cover all cases except one case in which a domain license should return `true` in `is_valid` xml node.

The REST API is so secured that it does not accept request from IPs that are not listed in their whitelist. And if someone is making a request from a non-whitelisted IP the API returns a `false` value for `is_valid` (and this is how I am covering the case for `false`)

I know this can be done using a mock object but I am not really sure how to write a mock object that can cover the case where a domain name is valid. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `'true'` is making it a `string`

Comment: yes, but still how do i test it?

Comment: try changing it from `'true'` to `true` (without the **`'`**'s)

Comment: I understand that, but how do I make the API return true??? because Like i said, the API does not work unless i m making the request from a whitelisted IP, in the above case I am making the request from my localhost....so i think i need to make a mock object,...kindly help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test this class, you would mock the Curl::Post call, but since it is done inline, you need to use Dependency Injection to use the Mock.

Class:

```
class ValidateLicense {
    private $svc;

    // Constructor Injection, pass the IntegratedService object here
    public function __construct($Service = NULL)
    {
        if(! is_null($Service) )
        {
            if($Service instanceof LicenseAPI)
            {
                $this->SetService($Service);
            }
        }
    }

    function SetService(LicenseAPI $Service)
    {
        $this->svc = $Service
    }

    function ValidLicense($domain) {
        $svc    = $this->svc;
        $result = $svc->IsLicenseValid($domain);
        return $result;
    }
}

class LicenseAPI {
    public function IsLicenseValid($domain)  
    {
        if( empty($domain)) {
            throw new Exception;
        }
        $licenseResponse = Curl::Post(['hostname' => $domain]);

        $Xml     = new XML();
        $xmlTree = $Xml->XMLToTree($licenseResponse);

        if ($xmlTree['is_valid'] == 'true') {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
class ValidateLicenseTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // Could also use dataProvider to send different returnValues, and then check with Asserts.
    public function testValidLicense()
    {
        // Create a mock for the LicenseAPI class,
        $MockService = $this->getMock('LicenseAPI', array('IsLicenseValid'));

        // Set up the expectation for the return method 
        $MockService->expects($this->any())
                    ->method('IsLicenseValid')
                    ->will($this->returnValue(true));

        // Create Test Object - Pass our Mock as the service
        $TestClass = new ValidateLicense($MockService);
        // Or
        // $TestClass = new ValidateLicense();
        // $TestClass->SetServices($MockService);

        // Test
        $domain = "localhost";  // Could be checked with the Mock functions
        $this->assertTrue($TestClass->ValidLicense($domain));
    }

    // Could also use dataProvider to send different returnValues, and then check with Asserts.
    public function testInValidLicense()
    {
        // Create a mock for the LicenseAPI class,
        $MockService = $this->getMock('LicenseAPI', array('IsLicenseValid'));

        // Set up the expectation for the return method 
        $MockService->expects($this->any())
                    ->method('IsLicenseValid')
                    ->will($this->returnValue(false));

        // Create Test Object - Pass our Mock as the service
        $TestClass = new ValidateLicense($MockService);
        // Or
        // $TestClass = new ValidateLicense();
        // $TestClass->SetServices($MockService);

        // Test
        $domain = "localhost";  // Could be checked with the Mock functions
        $this->assertFalse($TestClass->ValidLicense($domain));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but This does not seem to be working. Did u try it yourself? Here is the error I am getting. `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method ValidateLicense::IsLicenseValid()`

Comment: No, I did not try it, but basically tried to put together an example to show you how dependency injection would be used.  I have updated the function calls in the code, as they should call ValidLicense, not IsLicenseValud.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I noticed that using a mock does not do a 100% code coverage bcoz we are using some other class to meet a result. Can you confirm me the same please?

Comment: Correct, as the Mock does not execute the actual code, the code doing the library validation calls will not truly be run. You need to test some of that independently as well to increase your code coverage.  However, if you separate the code using the SOLID principle as much as possible, you can get to 100%, as the API code itself will be all that is not actually called. I then locate that code and others like it, in a separate directory, which I then ignore from code coverage, etc...

Comment: On a side note, if this did solve your problem, please accept the answer as it helps flag this for other users to know it works.